# How to sort a collection_radio_buttons object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following radio button that is currently sorting by default using the updated_at date/time.  I would instead like to sort by id.  [The docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons) say that you can specify order with a block but I can't seem to figure out the context.  Here's the radio button as is.  I'd like to add a sort based on id of the Infosessions.all description field:

```
          <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :investor, InfoSession.all, :id, :description,
                                      label: "Please select an investor session:",
                                      required: true,
                                      checked: 1,
                                      wrapper: { class: 'text-left'} %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a scope in your InfoSession model,

```
class InfoSession < ApplicationRecord
  scope :sorted_by_description, -> { order(description: :desc) } #default is :asc
end
```

then in your view (or better in controller, then pass to view),

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :investor, InfoSession.sorted_by_description, :id, :description,
           label: "Please select an investor session:",
           required: true,
           checked: 1,
           wrapper: { class: 'text-left'} %>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly.

Comment: with pleasure -))